# What is an alternative and easy way to test if Webform is in fact sending mail?

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I'm not sure if its the webform module or my server, but a few days ago i was receiving webform submissions via email, but today its not working when I did a test on the same webform. Is there a easy way to test if its webform that's the issue or my server?

Comment: You could have registered a user on your site or tested any other feature that involves sending out an email to check if server is at fault or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the [Mail Logger](https://drupal.org/project/mail_logger) or [Maillog](https://drupal.org/project/maillog) modules. That will enable you to see whether there is an email actually being created. I personally used to use the second, with D6 though.